# Where do I find the Quill of Gemination under Lake Honrich in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve tried to do this quest once or twice and I have no idea where to find it. It won’t even show me where it’s at. I’m playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 2):

The UESP article on the quest [Vald’s debt](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vald%27s_Debt) says that the quill is in Vald’s strongbox. UESP has an interactive [map](http://srmap.uesp.net/?centeron=Vald%27s+Strongbox) showing its location. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Vald’s strongbox]

Comment: @TrystanPost Glad to help. That map on UESP is really great for finding things like this.

Comment: Ill check the cite out sometime

Comment: @TrystanPost [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page) and [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skyrim) are fantastic resources. If you look through the Skyrim answers on this site, the vast majority have at least one link to one of these wikis. I highly recommend checking them before going to the effort of posting a question here.